# Issues with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 UWP App Development

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I'm new to Universal Windows Platform I'm unable to open my Universal Windows Platform Apps I get "**install universal windows platform tools and windows 10 sdk 10.0.10240**" even though I've the latest version of Windows 10 SDK. I tried repairing VS 2015 Update 1 un-installing and re-installing but still the issue persists. I even considered installing fresh copy of VS 2015 with Update 2 and installing standalone Windows 10 SDK but still no solution. Any related advice will be appreciated. You can view my Screenshot(s).
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=56829C722C837939!15916&authkey=!ADPIhg1RIJzUdqc&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=56829C722C837939!15917&authkey=!AHNLMj1bxtNw_9g&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have `TargetPlatformVersion` set to `10.0.240.0` in your .csproj file. While the latest SDK installed in system is of version `10.0.586.0` version.
I faced the same problem when i had uninstalled the `10.0.240.0` version and installed the latest SDK.
Got it working by changing to following lines in .csproj file under `PropertyGroup` tag:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

Reload the project in Visual Studio. It should work.

Comment: The same issue with the new CreatorsUpdate of Windows. Some computers have already been updated and committed the project with TargetPlatformVersion 10.0.15063.0, and now computers without this update (with AnniversaryUpdate, 10.0.14393.0) cannot open these projects and require an SDK update. So for now, we have to manually edit the project files.